# Tkinter Python Window Crashing When Slider Updated

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hi guys just wondering if anyone could give me some assistance. Trying to make a python script to control a greenhouse with a raspberry pi, still in early stages at the moment.

Problem is i need a certain section of code to loop so it continually keeps the correct temp, etc i want this to occur as long as a variable is equal to 1 this is controlled by a GUI button (and works fine). Just as a test i got the code to print the temprature (value) from the slider but when its changed the Tkinter window crashes (Not Responding). Anyone know the reason or have a fix.

Entire Code:#

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
import time

#--------------------VARIABLES--------------------#
ManOverideToggleINT = 0
AUTOMODETOGGLESTATEINT = 0
#------------------TKINTER SETUP------------------#
root.title("GREENHOUSE CONTROL - GUI")
root.geometry('800x480')
#root.attributes('-fullscreen', True) #MAKE IT FULL SCREEN UN-COMMENT WHEN CODE DONE


#---------------CONTROLS AUTO MODE----------------#
"""
This function will control the greenhouse when
manual overide in not engaged (==1), monitor temp,
humidity, etc.

MORE RESEARCH NEEDED ON PLANTS NEEDS
"""
def AUTO():
    global AUTOMODETOGGLESTATEINT
    while AUTOMODETOGGLESTATEINT == 0:
        print(CONSTEMP.get())
        time.sleep(5)
        """
##############
GPIO PINS NEEDED INPUTS/OUTPUTS
##############

        COOLING IF TOO WARM

        if (realtemp>CONSTEMP.get()):
            print("Cooling activated" + realtemp + " > " CONSTEMP.get() + " (desired)")
        COOLING OFF IF TOO WARM

        elif (realtemp<CONSTEMP.get()):
            print("Cooling deactivted" + realtemp + " < " CONSTEMP.get() + " (desired)")
        """
        print("AUTO LOOP HERE")
#--------------CONTROLS MANUAL MODE---------------#
"""
Manual mode will allows the user to specify
specific conditions inside the green house
"""
def MANUAL():
    global AUTOMODETOGGLESTATEINT
    if AUTOMODETOGGLESTATEINT == 1:
        print("AUTO REGULATION HAS BEEN TURNED OFF")
        print("LOOP UNTILL BACK ON")

#def ToggleWait():


def AUTOMODETOGGLE():
    global AUTOMODETOGGLESTATEINT
    if AUTOMODETOGGLESTATEINT == 0:
        print("Auto Mode OFF")
        TOGGLE["text"] = "AUTO REGULATION = OFF"
        AUTOMODETOGGLESTATEINT = 1
        MANUAL()
    else:
        print("AUTO REGULATION = ON")
        TOGGLE["text"] = "AUTO REGULATION = ON"
        AUTOMODETOGGLESTATEINT = 0
        AUTO()


TOGGLE = Button(root, text="AUTO REGULATION = ON", command=AUTOMODETOGGLE)
TOGGLE.pack()
CONSTEMP = Scale(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, width=50,from_=10,to=40,tickinterval=5,)#25c is optinum
CONSTEMP.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tk's event loop from running which is what keeps the program responsive.  When you run a while loop that never exits it blocks the mainloop and you lose responsiveness.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Any ideas how I could run both simultaneously or is there a work around?

Comment: easy, change `while ... == 0:` to just `if ... ==0:` and change `time.sleep(5)` to `root.after(5000, AUTO)` to schedule calling AUTO again after 5000ms (5 seconds)

Comment: That way it will act as a scheduled task to be called in the `mainloop` instead of a loop of its own.

Comment: Thanks everyone will see if that works much appreciated. Brilliant community on here have to say.